# Objective C classes cannot be recognized in swift after upgrade to Xcode 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode10, bridging-header

I have an iOS project which developed by both Swift 4 and Objective C, everything is fine when Xcode 9 is used.

After upgrade XCode to 10.0, my swift classes cannot recognize Objective C classes and libraries, which produce error

> '{project_name}-Swift.h' file not found

and

> Use of undeclared type 'xxxxx'

Latter error appears at least in the followings situations:

- System objective C class (such as UIImage, UIView...)
- Objective C class in cocoapods libraries (such as AFNetworking 2...)
- Custom objective c class
- `#define` variables in .h file

I am still using Swift 4 yet (not 4.2). Tried clean the build folder and remove DerivedData and build again, these errors are still exist.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue by moving one of the framework in Build Phases.

Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> (remove) framework

When look around Link Binary With Libraries, I notice there are some Frameworks which icon has a lighter color (seems deactive), after remove the framework and build again, things are okay.

For my case, I remove the Bolts framework which is installed accompany with Facebook SDK. Previously, I change to use Cocoapods to update Facebook SDK instead of adding the Facebook SDK library to the project manually.